# Deobfuscator and decompiler for .NET

Tags: decompilation, deobfuscation

Which are the most common and useful deobfuscators and decompilers for .NET .dll files?

Answer (score 2):

For decompilation, I recommend you to try [dnSpy](https://github.com/dnSpy/dnSpy). The console version of this tool (`dnSpy.Console.exe`) works on all platforms via `mono`.

For deobfuscation of most standard obfuscators, [de4dot](https://github.com/de4dot/de4dot) will help. Supported obfuscators/packers enumerated in README.
It should be noted that dnSpy supports the debugger with which you can unpack most non-standard packers by hands.

Comment: thank you, I am trying to decrypt a string using the method of de4dot with "--strtyp delegate" but I get following error: Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Invalid Image
File name: '/usr/lib/de4dot/AssemblyServer-x64.exe' I know the file is missing but I dont know how to install it either